drop row with 3 columns value equal
I would like to drop the row with all three columns have equal value. e.g.
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A',2,2,2],
    ['B',2,2,3],
    ['C',3,3,3],
    ['D',4,2,2],
    ['E',5,5,2]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','val1','val2','val3'])
print(df)


In above example, row 0 and row 2 will be dropped since the value is equal.

You can easily drop rows where specified columns have equal values using the following steps:
Step 1:
Use df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3']].nunique(axis=1) to calculate the number of unique values in each row across these columns.
Step2 :  where the number of unique values >= then filter the rows
Here is code snippet to guide you
#filters val1, val2, val3 is >=1
df_filterd = df[df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3']].nunique(axis=1) > 1]

print(df_filterd)


Result:
  name  val1  val2  val3
1    B     2     2     3
3    D     4     2     2
4    E     5     5     2

OR
You can drop rows where all values in val1, val2, val3 are equal , here is docs which you can use to reference it drop
df_drop = df[~df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3']].eq(df['val1'], axis=0).all(axis=1)]

print(df_drop)
  name  val1  val2  val3
1    B     2     2     3
3    D     4     2     2
4    E     5     5     2


Try:
print(df[df.loc[:, ["val1", "val2", "val3"]].nunique(axis=1).gt(1)])

Prints:
  name  val1  val2  val3
1    B     2     2     3
3    D     4     2     2
4    E     5     5     2

